Any connection between Custom Permissions and Profile?
I have a bunch of custom permissions added to all profiles in a Salesforce org, I wish to run an apex script to remove these permissions, However, I don't see any object like PermissionSetAssignment for the link between Custom permissions and Profiles.

I think you will find explicit fields added to the profile for each custom permission. Check the object model.

You can still have custom permissions "on profiles". Of course, you should use perm sets.

It's called SetupEntityAccess, which you can query to get the current permissions, and then delete.
String permName = 'Demo';
CustomPermission p = [SELECT Id FROM CustomPermission WHERE DeveloperName = :permName];
SetupEntityAccess[] sea = [SELECT Id FROM SetupEntityAccess WHERE SetupEntityId = :p.Id];
delete sea;

